# Evaluate the 2022nd derivative using Maclaurin series

Tags: calculus, derivatives, taylor-expansion, power-series

We have to evaluate $f^{(2022)}(0)$. Its the $2022$nd derivative of $f(x) = \frac{1}{4-{x^2}}$ at $x=0$.

As far as I know, the Maclaurin series is used here but I always got an incorrect power series for this.

It is said that the Maclaurin series is
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}{x^n}$$

and
$$C_k = \frac{f^{(k)}(a)}{k!}$$

But I don't get how to turn the power series representation of $f(x)$ into the series above and then evaluate the 2022nd derivative at $x=0$.

So far I got

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{2n}}{2^{2n+2}} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!}{x^{2n}}(*)$$ (*not so sure abt this one)

How can I solve for the Maclaurin series using the given $f(x)$?

Comment: [MathJax MSE](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Your last equality $(*)$ is wrong (the LHS is the sum of a geometric series, whereas the RHS is an exponential).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The power series of $f(x)= \frac{1}{a-x}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2717639/the-power-series-of-fx-frac1a-x) (replace $a$ by $4$ and $x$ by $x^2$).

Comment: If you want to calculate the Maclaurin series the direct way, you will have to differentiate $f$ 2022 times, which is exactly what you would do if you wanted to calculate the answer to the problem directly. There is a more clever way to use the Maclaurin series.

Comment: @AnneBauval Can you show the last equality?

Comment: I don't understand this question. Again: your last equality (∗) is wrong.